# How do I stop word splitting in bash for loop?

Tags: bash, big-sur

When I run the command below:

`mdfind -name iMazing`

I get the following output:

```
/Users/apple/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/iMazing.Versions
/Users/apple/Library/Application Support/com.DigiDNA.iMazing2Mac
```

I want to run a for a loop to delete these dirs.

Before doing so I tested with `ls`:

`for i in $(mdfind -name); do ls "$i"; done`

Output:

```
ls: /Users/apple/Library/Application: No such file or directory
ls: Support/MobileSync/Backup/iMazing.Versions: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/apple/Library/Application: No such file or directory
ls: Support/com.DigiDNA.iMazing2Mac: No such file or directory
```

As you can see word splitting has happened because of the space in `Application Support`

I tried the following variations:

`"${i}"`

Escaping the quotes:

`"\"$i"\"`

`"\"${i}"\"`

to no avail, any ideas?

**EDIT:**

So `IFS` does not matter, what's going on?:

```bsh
 kn: (master)  
 λ  IFS=; for i in $(mdfind -name iMazing); do ls "$i"; done
ls: /Users/apple/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/iMazing.Versions
/Users/apple/Library/Application Support/com.DigiDNA.iMazing2Mac: No such file or directory
  kn: (master)  
 λ  while IFS= read -r i; do ls "$i"; done < <(mdfind -name iMazing)
Blueprints  Readme.txt  Temp        Trash       Versions
com.microsoft.appcenter
  kn: (master)  
 λ  while read -r i; do ls "$i"; done < <(mdfind -name iMazing)
Blueprints  Readme.txt  Temp        Trash       Versions
com.microsoft.appcenter
```

Comment: I'd use this method instead: `while IFS= read -r line; do echo rm -R "$line"; done < <(mdfind -name iMazing)` Run it first with the `echo` _command_  to see you like the output, then remove the `echo` from the _compound command_ and run it again.  Note that with the  `echo` _command_ the output will not be quoted but it will be when run without the `echo` _command_.

Comment: @user3439894 why does this method work? I tried setting `IFS=' '` but that still didn't make my for loop work, I'm just interested

Comment: in fact even without IFS your cmd works `while read -r line; do ls "$line"; done < <(mdfind -name iMazing)`

Comment: [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not the quoting of `$i` — that's too late.

The for loop has already split the input by spaces, so each for loop iteration is being given one of the four components shown in the errors. You need to fix the loop instead.

You can do this by setting IFS, the Internal Field Separator, to newline.

```
IFS=$'\n'; for i in $(mdfind -name iMazing); do ls "$i"; done
```

IFS is how bash determines how to split input. By default, it includes space, so each space in each line of the input is split into two inputs, alongside the existing new lines, causing 4 loops rather than 2. Setting IFS to new line only turns off this splitting by space, preserving each line of input without additional splitting.

---

A potentially preferable way of looping over **lines** of output is using `read -r line`:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo rm -R "$line"; done < <(mdfind -name iMazing)
```

Unix.SE has a good breakdown of `IFS= read -r line`:

- [Understanding “IFS= read -r line”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123/45383)

Comment: I remember using `IFS=$'\n'` in bash scripts where vars had spaces, I'm going to give you the answer since you fixed my for loop but if you could explain how the `while read -r line` loop works without `IFS` that would be a nice bonus :)

Comment: @Nick For IFS in the `read` case, this is explained in the linked Unix.SE Q&A: *"if you don't need any of the preceding and trailing whitespace characters you could just write read -r line and be done with it."*

Comment: The safest way to do it is with null-delimited entries; use `while IFS= read -r -d '' line` and `done < <(mdfind -0 -name iMazing)`. The `read -d ''` and `mdfind -0` are the critical changes. See [BashFAQ #20](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) for some similar examples.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to pass the results to a single command (not run a sequence of commands, or anything complex like that), you can use `xargs`. If the command can take a bunch of filenames at once, use something like this:

```
mdfind -0 -name iMazing | xargs -0 ls
```

The `-0` options make the commands use null bytes as delimiters; since these cannot occur in filenames, this is safe against all the usual confusions.

Note: if you're going to use this with something dangerous, like `rm`, I recommend running it with something safe, like `ls`, to make sure it's going to do what you want. (And... you have a good backup, right?) If you want to be really careful, add the `-p` option (after `xargs`, but before the command to be executed) and it'll print the command and ask for confirmation before running it.

Also, if the command can't take a bunch of filenames at once, add `-n 1` (again, after `xargs` but before the command).

Answer (score 3):

If you install a version of bash >= 4.0 (say, with Homebrew), you can do:

```bsh
mapfile -t files < <(mdfind -name iMazing)
```

which reads the *lines* of the mdfind output into the "files" array. Then

```bsh
for file in "${files[@]}"; do ls "$file"; done
```

Comment: what’s the benefit of this over `while read  -r line`? Seems like it just gives you more to do but I’m interested if you can describe a case where it’s more useful

Comment: @Nickotine The main advantage is that you can do things other than iterate over the list once. So if you want use it multiple times, process it, etc. BTW, there's a also a null-delimited (safer) version of this, provided you have bash v4.4 or later: `mapfile -d '' -t files < <(mdfind -0 -name iMazing)`

Comment: @gordonDavisson I like the idea I could use it for other stuff, thank you. I have bash 5 which I got with brew, but for this case since I’m deleting the files I don’t think I need it, but it’s a pretty cool feature :)

Comment: @Nickotine In that case, it's even easier -- just use `xargs`. I'll submit an answer in a minute.